# Riley Riddle #7: To Be Of Service

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

First the time named for the Great Giant's wife.
Last a desperate source of power or strife.
Betwixt first find 10, then 21 in the first book.
Don't get pricked by this red treat you don't need to cook.

Hint 1:

> The suffix is a common trope in survivalist stories. The infix is found in a book of books: look for a proper noun in the specified place.

Comment: Is the last line talking about red herring

Comment: Nope! That's a nice try, but I wouldn't think it a treat.

Comment: Plus the last line describes the one word the rest of the clues come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @Eutherpy & @Rand al'Thor's answer that the prefix is talking about

> JUNE.

I think that the infix is talking about

> either Shem or Eber, found in Genesis 10:21 (the first book of the Bible, a book of books). Since the prefix ends in E, let's go with EBER.

The suffix could be

> BERRY, since in survivalist novels, having berries or any kind of food would give the holder power over people who don't have it. It can also cause people to fight over it, if the berries are scarce in the post-apocalyptic society.

If we put everything together, I think the answer is hinting at

> JUNEBERRY, also known as the Saskatoon berry, a delicious red fruit that does not require cooking.

---

*Further explanation from OP:*

> For the suffix, in essentially every survivalist story I've read (think: hunger games), the protagonists are hungry and they find some berries and the berries are either what they need to sustain themselves (a source of power) or will kill them (strife). The juneberry is part of the rose family, hence why you don't want to get pricked, since roses often have thorns :P. As for the title, juneberries are also known as serviceberries.

Comment: Is the suffix really that mysterious? :P I'll tell you you've got the whole word right, surely you can find the suffix now.

Comment: Could it be the most obvious suffix? @flashstorm

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> JUNIPER,

although I haven't fully understood all the clues.

*First the time named for the Great Giant's wife.*

> As Eutherpy already spotted, this means **JUNE** - the Great Giant is Jupiter, whose wife is Juno, after whom the month of June is named.

*Last a desperate source of power or strife.*

> This one I'm not sure about. How is **PER** a source of power or strife? Perhaps because power is energy *per* time??

*Betwixed first find 10, then 21 in the first book.*

> This sounds like something to do with Roman numerals, but 10 is X and 21 is XXI. Somehow "the first book" involves putting these together to leave just **I**?

*Don't get pricked by this red treat you don't need to cook.*

> Judging from the pictures of juniper berries I've found online, they're often blue but sometimes red. And the bush is quite prickly.

Comment: Your answers are $99.9\%$ good, so I upvoted before looking at what you thought :)

Comment: @user477343 I'm flattered, but please upvote based on the quality of the answer, not who posted it :-)

Comment: I think you can understand why the middle and end clues aren't correct. Your whole post does contain one of the answers to one of the clues, though, just not in the right place! :)

Comment: Well, after looking at it, I think it deserves an upvote. It makes enough sense to me, even if @flashstorm says it is not correct :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think that r13(Whar) or some variant of that is the infix -- this is because r13(gur gragu vf W naq gur gjragl-svefg vf H).

Comment: @flashstorm Following El-Guest's comment, could the answer be rot13(whwhor)?

Comment: rot13(Jung obbx bs obbxf qb gubfr pbzr sebz?)

Comment: Based on @flashstorm's comments, I had another thought regarding the infix...

Answer (score 2):

I think the first line might be

> June, since the "Great Giant" might be Jupiter, and Juno (Junone) in mythology is the wife of Jupiter.

Other than that, I haven't got a clue... this one's tough! :)